# Searching for French noun with very specific criteria

Tags: vocabulaire, noms, diacritiques, voyelles, humour

I am writing a book of humor and I would be happy to send a free copy to the person who sends the best response.  I am looking for a French feminine noun that has one acute accent.  The word cannot have any other accents. Also, the word needs to have a vowel sound that appears at least twice within the word.  As an example, I believe the French word for “the household,” "la maisonnée," meets the criteria.  Please let me know if you know of any other words--the more unusual the word, the better.  I prefer that the word has an ending that is obviously feminine, as in the example above, but that is not necessary.  Merci beaucoup!

Comment: Could you tell us what you want to use the word for? The name of an inn? Of a band? That might guide us a little, because there are tons of words that meet this criteria.

Comment: Something related to a bar or tavern would be preferred, but it's not required.  Anything you can send along would be great.  Plus I forgot to mention that the word does need to include a diphthong!  Thanks for your interest in helping with this--I really appreciate it!

Comment: Well there are no diphtongs in French, so your second conditions is gonna be a little hard to fulfill ^^ Maybe you meant something else?

Answer (score 1):

**peignée**

[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/peign%C3%A9e)

> **A.** *Pop., fam. Volée de coups.* Synon. *raclée, rossée, volée. Donner, flanquer une peignée à qqn; recevoir une peignée; se donner, se foutre une peignée. Alors, on se trépignait dans la chambre vide, des peignées à se faire passer le goût du pain. Mais elle finissait par se ficher des dégelées comme du reste* (ZOLA, *Assommoir*, 1877, p. 751). *On parle des peignées homériques entre les soeurs de Gautier et la Grisi, d'entre lesquelles s'échappait Gautier, les laissant placidement continuer à s'arracher les cheveux* (GONCOURT, *Journal*, 1895, p. 876). *À l'ordinaire j'étais calme, plutôt trop doux, et je détestais les peignées, convaincu sans doute que j'y aurais toujours le dessous* (GIDE, *Si le grain*, 1924, p. 408). V. *fouailler* ex. 1.
>   **B.** TEXT.  ,,*Quantité de laine ou de chanvre que l'ouvrier met sur son peigne*`` (CHESN. t.2 1858).